# How to classify anomalies between two sound datasets?

Tags: classification, anomaly-detection

I have two sound datasets and each one has 80% normal and 20% anomalous data points. The first one is a rock song and the second one is a mellow indie song. I use half of the normal data as a baseline in each dataset. I identify anomalies using isolation forest in each dataset and found 25 anomalies in the first rock song dataset and 12 in the mellow threshold. Now my question is how can I classify an anomaly as a rock song specific one? Do you think building a simple linear regression classifier should work?

Comment: When you ask "Now my question is how can I classify an anomaly as a rock song specific one?", are you asking how to find anomalies that are **specific to** the rock song rather than "general anomalies"?

Comment: yes. sorry for the confusion.